# Problems with org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c and Org 9.0

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I recently installed Org 9.0 and ‘org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c’ often complains about 
`user-error: ‘C-c C-c’ can do nothing useful here`. However when I use it repeatedly it works suddenly, although I didn't change anything ?

Comment: I have found in code blocks if you are on a blank line I get that error. I haven't had time to track it down or check if it is fixed.

Comment: I agree. I have been having the same issue for a while. My current solution is to move to lines that have source code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `org` and `org-plus-contrib` packages and reinstall to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

@John Kitchin thanks. I will use this temporary fix.

```
(defun my-org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c ()
  "Fix blank line issue."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-babel-goto-src-block-head)
    (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)))
```